# Having issues going back to windows after fully deleting windows and installing Ubuntu

Tags: boot, partitioning, system-installation, windows, usb-installation

So I bought a Dell xps 1970 and installed Ubuntu after a lot of complications. After having used Ubuntu I miss Windows a lot however I have googled for ages and can't find a good solution. Here is what I know:
I don't have a dual boot, I overwrote Windows with Ubuntu.

I bought a 16 GB USB and then I formatted it accordingly:

[image: Picture of the partition]

Then I used some guides (there were multiple) and Finally succeeded in copying the contents of an ISO Windows file that I got from the official Microsoft site to the USB . I Then checked to see if it had the right contents and by the looks of it, it looked correct.[image]

Then I restarted my computer to try and boot from the USB, however the USB was not visible.
I have it in the right side port (I saw that matters). The usb is bootable. I have the options in BIOS active for booting on a usb. Why can't I see it? Secure boot is off, AHCI is selected.

My goal is just to go back to when I first bought the computer, with windows on.

Edit: I saw somewhere that you need to have Legacy on to see USB? but for some reason I can't put it on in BIOS?

Comment: While contents look correct, it cannot be a UDF or hybrid ISO DVD/flash configuration. And newest Windows has a .wim file that is over 4GB so does not fit on FAT32 partition. But UEFI requires FAT32 to boot in UEFI mode. When I created a Windows installer using my Windows it changed the .wim file into two smaller files to fit correctly. Not sure how to create unless you have Windows. Some older instructions only work with older Windows where .wim was less than 4GB.

Comment: So you're telling me that a FAT32 partition has a limited amount of space? But that it is needed to boot in UEFI mode? I Thought the space was dependant on the USB? What does this really mean? That I cant get back?

Comment: FAT32 is intended only for smaller drives/partitions. It has a 4GB limit on file size and no journal. Journal not really required on smaller partitions, but helps with file recovery on larger partitions. Not sure if Dell has a vendor image you can download, most used to as they had unique drivers, but now expect you to use Windows and add drivers manually. You can call Dell, say you have no backup and system not working. Do not mention you installed Linux.